# Adding an ImageButton at user touch Android

Tags: android, android-button, android-image

I have a canvas which the user is able to add icons to which represent real world appliances. However, is it possible to dynamically create ImageButtons instead of just icons? If not is there any easy way of listening for user touches on the icons to execute code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) to see if the user click somewhere inside the image.

Comment: How would I localize touch to the icons though? Just to clarify - the icons aren't present before the user has drawn them. So I can't tie code to a specific area of screen.

Comment: You mean it's kind of a drawing program you are making?

Answer (score 0):

For touching the icon and receiving the callback, you can use onTouchListener.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

    return false;
}
```

see more about onTouch 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: How would I localize touch to the icons though? Just to clarify - the icons aren't present before the user has drawn them. So I can't tie code to a specific area of screen.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem and share some more information. Then it will be easy to answer